# SUM results of multiple COUNT (UNION) SQL query

Tags: sql-server, count, sum

I'm trying to add the results of a `UNION` `COUNT` query together to get a 'total' easily.   My SQL query is a simple `UNION`, can anyone advise how I can add the results generated to give me a total?

```
SELECT 'BOXES' AS DATASET,  
       COUNT(RECORD_TABLE) AS RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE
FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_SEARCH 
WHERE RECORD_TABLE = 'TB_BOXES'
GROUP BY RECORD_TABLE 
UNION 
SELECT 'MAPS' AS DATASET,  
       COUNT(RECORD_TABLE) AS RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE
FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_SEARCH 
WHERE RECORD_TABLE = 'MAPS'
GROUP BY RECORD_TABLE
```

My results look like the below, I'd like to add a 'TOTAL' column with the total number of records.

```
DATASET      RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE
TB_BOXES     3149
TB_MAPS      856
```

Comment: Wrap that union as CTE and select total from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Record_Table, COUNT(Record_Table) Records_In_Archive
FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_Search
WHERE Record_Table IN ('Maps','TB_Boxes')
GROUP BY Record_Table
ORDER BY Record_Table
)
SELECT ISNULL(Case Record_Table WHEN 'TB_Boxes' THEN 'Boxes' ELSE Record_Table 
END,'Total') Record_Table,
SUM(Records_In_Archive) Records_In_Archive
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Case Record_Table WHEN 'TB_Boxes' THEN 'Boxes' ELSE Record_Table END 
WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY Record_Table
```

Although, if you are looking for a separate result:

```
SELECT 'Total', COUNT(Record_Table)
FROM dbo.VIEW_Global_Search
WHERE Record_Table IN ('TB_Boxes','Maps')
```

Why overthink this?

Comment: Unions are horrible - performance wise. Leverage SQL to filter the initial dataset to get the values you want, and on the filtered set, do the aggregation required to solve the logic you need. Group by has WITH ROLLUP, and WITH CUBE... for summing totals in 1 query.

Comment: Thanks for the information Alocyte - I will look in to using ROLLUP and WITH CUBE in the future to sum totals within a single query as that is basically what I am after.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Common Table Expression for your `UNION` should to the trick:

```
WITH rawdata AS (
  SELECT 'BOXES' AS DATASET,  
       COUNT(RECORD_TABLE) AS RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE
  FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_SEARCH 
    WHERE RECORD_TABLE = 'TB_BOXES'
  GROUP BY RECORD_TABLE 
UNION 
  SELECT 'MAPS' AS DATASET,  
       COUNT(RECORD_TABLE) AS RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE
  FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_SEARCH 
    WHERE RECORD_TABLE = 'MAPS'
  GROUP BY RECORD_TABLE
) SELECT SUM(RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE) FROM rawdata;
```

Comment: Thanks Jan, that worked and has given me a total of the number of records.  Thanks for taking the time to look.

Answer (score 0):

you mean add new row for total ?

```
SELECT RECORD_TABLE AS DATASET,  
       COUNT(RECORD_TABLE) AS RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE 
FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_SEARCH 
WHERE RECORD_TABLE IN ('TB_BOXES', 'MAPS')
GROUP BY RECORD_TABLE 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL' AS DATASET,  
       COUNT(RECORD_TABLE) AS RECORDS_IN_ARCHIVE 
FROM dbo.VIEW_GLOBAL_SEARCH 
WHERE RECORD_TABLE IN ('TB_BOXES', 'MAPS');
```